# why is svn.remote.RemoteClient() not working on centos server while it works on windows?

Tags: python, svn, remote-access, pypi

I  have installed svn :  `pip install svn` on centos.

I am using `svn.remote.RemoteClient(url,username,password)`to connect to 
    remote svn host as per `pypi` documentation. But my code is throwing

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

> NOTE: Same code works on my windows desktop. On my windows I am able to do
>
> r = svn.remote.RemoteClient(url,username,password)
>       print (r.info)
>
> I have tried googling about the solution already.
>    I have tried setting up the proxy on the server.

```py
def validate(svnurl,username,password):
    import svn.remote
    try:
        r = svn.remote.RemoteClient(svnurl,username,password)
        info = r.info()
        return "valid"
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        print( "<p>Error: %s</p>" % e )
        return "not valid"

a=validate("url",'username','password')
print (a)
```

```
Expected result : valid
Error :
  File "validatecredentials.py", line 7, in validate
  info = r.info()

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in 
  _execute_child
  raise child_exception
  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

The python library wraps the `svn` commandline client. Do you have `svn` binaries in the system? Install them with

```
sudo yum install subversion
```